# Phonegap persistent app in background, how to?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

i have a Phonegap and JQM app.

Problem is, if I switch to another app and then back to my app, App is completely reloaded and start again.

Is posible this disable?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: You should read up on the Android Activity Lifecycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because there is a lack of memory for the app to run. So as soon as u go to home the app dies and on opening again it reloads the app from the start. To confirm that this is indeed happening i would suggest that you close all running apps on your phone and then run your app. Im sure it would run properly even after switching to home screen and coming back.
I don't think its possible to get around this behavior. Design your app so that it has a small startup time so that its usable even on phones with less ram where such problems would come.